# How to add a hole in QGraphicsPathItem?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I try to use `QGraphicsPathItem` draw a rounded rectange, and then add a hole in the rectange.I think it can do in the `paint` method, but the performance is not well. So is't there have a good way to draw the shape?

**Code Snippet**

```py
class Item(QGraphicsPathItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.addRect(-30, -39, 60, 78)
        path.addEllipse(QPoint(-30, 0),  39, 39)
        path.addEllipse(QPoint(30, 0),  39, 39)

        #add  a hole 
        path.addEllipse(QPoint(0, 0), 28.5, 28.5)

        # path.setFillRule(Qt.WindingFill)
        self.setBrush(Qt.blue)
        self.setPath(path)
```

**Wanted shape**
[image]

**My shape**
[image]

Comment: Try with just `path.addRoundedRect(-69, -39, 138, 78, 39, 39)` and the last `addEllipse`.

Comment: In my scene, I had to draw two circle, one rectangle, and the add a hole in the shape.For my scene, there have many different  shape that need to add different hole.

Comment: Do you need to draw two circles, one rectangle and the hole, or do you need to draw the "wanted shape"? Because, in the first case, you should have explained that (since you *explicitly* said a different thing), in the second, have you tried my code above?!

Comment: Yes,I try and can work.But In my post,I don't want to change the basis shape.

Comment: thanks for  your help, I had test a method that can work.

Comment: Your "basis shape" is actually a composite of 4 different shapes that collide and fill in different ways, so it's not "basic" at all. If you need to keep track of the circles and rectangle for collision detection of those specific items, then use internal QPainterPaths, otherwise you have to use `toFillPolygon()` (ensuring that you use the `Qt.WindingFill` rule) and then create a new path to which you will add the "hole".